# Should i change EXISTING (NOT NEW) Urls with underscores to hyphens for SEO?

Tags: seo, url, url-rewriting, ecommerce

Please note that this is for existing URLs, not new.

I know that Google says it is recommended to have Url's to display a hyphen(-) instead of a underscore(_) in the url as a keyword seperator otherwise google views it as one phrase.

We plan to convert all our website Urls to this format.

However, the problem is that the Urls have existed for years and have a significant google ranking.

I know that the would be a dip in SEO ranking if we change them but we can obviously use 301 to reduce that.

Realistically, would it be better for our SEO if we simply kept these Url's as they are and instead use hyphens on new urls we create or would it be better to change all the existing Urls from underscores to hyphen and 301 them to their new locations?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry but there already dozens of questions and answers regarding hyphens and redirecting old to new urls using 301 on Pro Webmasters already.

Comment: Where? I have searched and can't find one that is identical to my question?